# Not returning the amount of sample requested

Tags: python, list, function, loops

I tried using this code to run 10000+ samples in num_months, but it's only limiting me to 9000+ samples. Not sure why this is happening.

```
    def simulate_demand(num_months):
        simulated_months =[0]
        for months in range(num_months-1):
            simulated_months.append(rng.choice([1,0],p=[0.7,0.3]))

        simulated_months_distribution = [rng.normal(800,150)]

        for x in range(len(simulated_months)):
            if simulated_months[x] == 1:
                simulated_months_distribution.append(rng.normal(500,100))

            elif simulated_months[x] == 0:


                last_promotion = 0

                months_number = 1 

                while simulated_months[x-months_number] == 1:
                    last_promotion += 1
                    months_number += 1

                    if simulated_months[x-months_number] == 0:
                        t = last_promotion

                        simulated_months_distribution.append(rng.normal(800+(100*t),150))
        simulated_months_distribution_df = pd.DataFrame(simulated_months_distribution)
        simulated_months_distribution_df.plot(style='r--', figsize=(20,10))
        return simulated_months_distribution_df
```

Comment: what is `rng.choice` is `rng` a package or your own class?

Comment: That first `for` loop is only selecting 70% of the months.  That inner `while` loop is only going to run if this month was a 0 and the previous month was a 1.  That means you'll be missing 0.3x0.3 (where both this and the previous month were 0), or about 10% of your results, and that matches what you see.

Comment: rng is defined as rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=2). Thanks for the helpful comments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the `if` statement in the while loop. It's only run if there is at least 1 `simulated_month` with `1` before a `0`. This doesn't happen always, and thus you are missing some simulated distributions.

I believe what you want if to append the distribution even if that's not the case. The while loop is only for incrementing the `t` and subsequently, the mean of the distribution.

The solution is then to move the `if` out of the `while` loop. And the `if` is actually not necessary since it will always be true after the `while` loop.

```
def simulate_demand(num_months):
    simulated_months = [0]
    for months in range(num_months - 1):
        simulated_months.append(rng.choice([1, 0], p=[0.7, 0.3]))

    simulated_months_distribution = [rng.normal(800, 150)]

    for x in range(len(simulated_months)):
        if simulated_months[x] == 1:
            simulated_months_distribution.append(rng.normal(500, 100))

        elif simulated_months[x] == 0:

            last_promotion = 0

            months_number = 1

            while simulated_months[x - months_number] == 1:
                last_promotion += 1
                months_number += 1

            # the if is not necessary since it's always true after the while loop
            t = last_promotion

            # this should be run regardless whether the while loop runs so it should be outside
            simulated_months_distribution.append(rng.normal(800 + (100 * t), 150))

    simulated_months_distribution_df = pd.DataFrame(simulated_months_distribution)
    simulated_months_distribution_df.plot(style='r--', figsize=(20, 10))
    return simulated_months_distribution_df
```